# Create many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, database, jdbc, many-to-many

I need to make a many-to-many relationship between my `user` and `project` entities. For now the relationship between them is many-to-one. I tried searching how to do many-to-many in `JDBC`, but couldn't find anything useful. I know that I need a third table used to connect them, but don't really know how to make the query for it, and what additional classes do I need. Any kind of help is welcomed. The code so far is :

```
package com.TO;

public class User {
private String login;
private String password;
private String fullName;
private String role;

private String projectKey;

//constructor, setters and getters
}
```

---

```
package com.DAO;

import com.TO.User;
import com.Utills.JDBCUtil;

public class UserDAO {

  public static String getTableString(){
     String projectTable =  "create table user_db ( " +
                            "login varchar(20) not null, " +
                            "password varchar(20), " +
                            "full_name varchar(80), " +
                            "role varchar(2), " +
                            "project_key varchar(50), " +
                            "primary key(login))";
     return projectTable;
  } 
}
```

---

```
package com.TO;

public class Project {
  private String key;
  private String title;

  //constructor, setters and getters
}
```

---

```
package com.DAO;

public class ProjectDAO {

  public static String getTableString(){
    String projectTable =   "create table project ( " +
                            "project_key varchar(50) not null, " +
                            "title varchar(50), " +
                            "primary key(project_key))";
    return projectTable;        
  } 
}
```

PS: The `getTableString` methods are used in another class for creating the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDBC doesn't create relation between tables it allows you to perform queries over a database. Your question has nothing to do with JDBC or any other way to access a relational database from a java code. It's just a matter of creating your database model.

What you need for a many to many relation in a relational database is relation table between the 2 tables you want to link.

See [there](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) for further information

Comment: Thanks :). Any idea what the sql string for creating the relation table beetween the two tables, should be?

Comment: Oh don't woorry, I just found out that the primary key can be of several fields. This solves the previous question.

Answer (score 2):

How about having creating two array lists: 
Implement in user and array list to hold all its projects:

```
 ArrayList<Project> elements = new ArrayList<>();
```

And in Project, and array list to hold all its Users :

```
 ArrayList<User> elements = new ArrayList<>();
```

You have to update those when ever a user is assigned or removed from a Project.